# Schema.org markup for services with main and sub categories

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to markup with Schema.org and Microdata three different kind of services containing a main category and subcategories.

Is the code below correct?

Should I use the `hasOfferCatalog`? And if yes how should I apply it to the code below?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">

    <h2 class="article-heading" itemprop="category">Main service category 1</h2>
    <p>
        <span itemprop="serviceType">service 1</span> 
        <span itemprop="serviceType">service 2</span>
    </p>

    <h2 class="article-heading" itemprop="category">Main service category 2</h2>
    <p>
        <span itemprop="serviceType">service 1</span> 
        <span itemprop="serviceType">service 2</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple different services, you need to create multiple `Service` items.

Currently your markup means that there is *one* `Service` with two categories and four service types.

If it’s really one `Service` but with different kinds of offers, using the [`hasOfferCatalog` property](http://schema.org/hasOfferCatalog) would be appropriate.